# Sagemaker S3 folder not fully iterate

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I used for loop to iterate S3 bucket folder and to filter out the JSON files from the folder.
There are about 30,000 files in S3 bucket folder and about 15,000 of them are JSON File.
When I iterate the folder, I only can filter out about 300 of them.
No error occurred!

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id="xxxxxx",
    aws_secret_access_key="xxxxxxx",
)
data = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='rawdata',
    Prefix='mixedfiles',
)

json_files = [content["Key"] for content in data["Contents"] if content["Key"].endswith(".json")]

for json_file in json_files:
    print(json_file)
```

Update:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket = 'rawdata',
    Prefix = 'mixedfiles'
)

for page in response_iterator:
    for content in page['Contents']:
        if content['Key'].endswith('.json'):
            result_json = content['Key']
            print(result_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html).

See https://adamj.eu/tech/2018/01/09/using-boto3-think-pagination/ for more

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket')
for page in pages:
    for obj in page['Contents']:
        do_something(obj)
```

Comment: I tried paginator, but infinitely looping the first 300 json files I mentioned.

Comment: So it looks like you have a bug in your code... You will have to share it

Comment: Updated on my post